# How to receive float value from the serial port for the device side(sky mote)

Tags: c, contiki

I want to communicate my tmote sky with my arduino through uart to pass float to tmote-sky. I have already pass a string of "hello world" from pc to tmote sky but cannot find a way how to pass float from pc to tmote-sky.

I have tried to send Integer like 5 but it receive 5408.

```
 #include "contiki.h"
 #include "dev/serial-line.h"

 PROCESS(main_process, "main process");
 AUTOSTART_PROCESSES(&main_process);

 PROCESS_THREAD(main_process, ev, data)
 {
     PROCESS_BEGIN();
     for(;;) {
        PROCESS_WAIT_EVENT();

       if (ev == serial_line_event_message && data != NULL) {
       printf("got input string: '%s'\n", (const char *) data);
                 }
              }
       PROCESS_END();
 }
```

this is the code to receive string from pc. What changes I have to made to pass a float or integer.

I want that if i send 10.48 from my pc then it is also received as 10.48 on tmote sky.

Comment: Convert the string to a `float`? The [`strtof`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtof) function could be useful.

Comment: How did you send the integer? And how did you receive it? If you want to transfer binary data, you need to agree on represenation / byte order between sender and receiver. And on size of data types. As an alternative convert to string for sending on the UART.

Comment: For sending integer i just changed  printf("got input string: '%s'\n", (const char *) data) to  printf("got input string: '%d'\n", (const char *) data);